# Adding items in DOM with jQuery without browser scrollbar update

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, scrollbar, append

I am adding many <li> to a <ul> using jQuery with the append method.

When there is more <li> than the browser space can accomodate, I expected the vertical scrollbar to enable scrolling but it doesn't show at all.

I have tried this in Firefox and Chrome and the effect is the same.

Comment: Can you post some example HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the problem was caused because of the ExtJS Layout system I was using...

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like you have a css issue.  Scrollbars are determined by the css overflow property.

try

```
#myul {
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

or

```
#myul {
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: overflow:auto doesn't change anything, while overflow:scroll adds gray bars where both vertical and horizontal scrollbars would show... even if they are not needed. What I need is the browser to ajust it's own scrollbar, not ul's.